# How to change password for virtual Windows 7 installed using VMWare?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, passwords, vmware-fusion

I run a virtual Windows 7 on host OS Mac OS X 10.6.8 using VMWare Fusion 3.1.3.  How to change password for Windows 7?

EDIT:

When seeing the following

[image]

I sent a Ctrl-Alt-Del signal from VMWare menu then get

[image]

What do I do then?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, just open the Start Menu, and type "change password" and hit Enter. You'll find that many things you want to do in Windows are easily accessible by simply typing them within the start menu. Try it, tying things such as "make words bigger" or "add a printer", and you'll find it will show you the right option.

Answer (score 0):

Choose VM > Send Ctrl+Alt+Del then "Change Password". If you're trying to change the currently logged in user.

If a local user right click Computer > Local Users and Groups > Users > Right click on user to change password.

Comment: This didn't work.  See edit in my post.